# Social network app architecture with React+Nodejs and Kafka

Tags: node.js, reactjs, apache-kafka

I have an idea of social network website and as I'm currently learning web development I thought that was a great idea to practice. I already worked out the business logic and front-end design with React. Now it's time for backend and I'm struggling.

I want to create a React+Nodejs event-driven app. It seems logical to use Kafka right away. I looked through various Kafka architecture examples and have several questions:

1. Is it possible to create an app that uses Kafka for data through API calls from Nodejs and to React and vice versa. And user relational database only for longterm storage?
2. Is it better to use Kafka to handle all events but communicate with some noSQL database like Cassandra or HBase. Then it seems that NodeJS will have to make API calls to them and send data to React.
3. Am I completely missing the point and talking nonsense?

Comment: It's not really clear why you think you'd need Kafka. gRPC can handle event driven flows between applications... Your React app won't be a Kafka consumer, so not clear where you'd be processing events to respond to them either

Answer (score 0):

Any answer to this question is going to be quite opinion based, so I'm just going to try to stick to the facts.

1. It is totally possible to create such an application. Moreover, Kafka is basically a distributed log, so you can use it as an event store and build your state from that.
2. That mainly depends on your architecture, and there are too many gaps here to answer this with any certainty - what kind of data are you saving? What kind of questions will you need answered? What does your domain model look like? You could use Kafka as a store, or as a persistent messaging service.
3. I don't think you're off the mark, but perhaps you're going for the big guns when in reality you don't really need them. Kafka is great for a very large volume of events going through. If you're building something new, you don't have that volume. Perhaps start with something simpler that doesn't require so much operational complexity.